# two views with same id

Tags: android

How does android use `R.id.id_name` to find views after inflating the XML?

1.Suppose I have two XML's with one button each with same id.

2.I have inflated them and converted them into views

3.In R.id class only one `int` will be created for both the buttons.

How does android differentiate these buttons with same id Using same Resource name(R.id.id_name) .

Comment: Related post - [Can I use the same id in different layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12333624/465053)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The ID is not a unique reference.

However, in practice, you differentiate by using the parent view.

If we consider that 'this' is an Activity, set up with a layout that contains your buttons, then:

```
Button button = (Button) this.findViewById( R.id.id_name );
```

will return the first one it finds in the layout (I think - not sure the actual behaviour is defined).

However what you might do is call `findViewById` on some parent view that contains only one such instance with that ID.

```
LinearLayout okParent = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById( R.id.okLayout );
LinearLayout cancelParent = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById( R.id.cancelLayout );

Button okButton = (Button) okParent.findViewById( R.id.id_name );
Button cancelButton = (Button) cancelParent.findViewById( R.id.id_name );
```

Conceptually, this is a sort of path based lookup. You should be careful to design your layouts such that this is possible.

Comment: That's why its ID (short for Identifier) & not UID (Unique Identifier). There are UUIDs too which mean Universally Unique Identifiers.

Answer (score 23):

Android takes the easy road: **IDs are not application-wide unique, but layout-wide unique.**

The value of `R.id.foo` is the same across two different layouts holding a control with `foo` id. Since they are not competing for uniqueness, it doesn't matter.

Comment: slick! very nice approach taken by android

Answer (score 7):

It knows which `View` should it use, because it looks for `View` with this specific `id` in a XML file that is currently set as content view (or is inflated).