# textview copies either next or previous text when copied in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager which displays text in textview from List.but when copied text from current viewpager it either copies next or previous text.
here is my mainactivity method code :-

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.copyid:

            TextView  msg= (TextView) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            String msgs=msg.getText().toString();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,msgs);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share Via"));
            break;
    }
```

and in viewpager adapter class:-

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layour,null);
    msg= (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    msg.setText(list.get(position));
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0);

    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access the `list` in `onOptionsItemSelected` then you can use

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
       case R.id.copyid:

        int i = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        String msgs= i>=0?list.get(i):"";
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,msgs);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share Via"));
        break;


}
```

It will be faster. In your code the problem is with the duplicate id of `TextView` . Have a look on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14759249/5969624)

Comment: Thanks bro. Perfect solution

Comment: @AkashK If you think this answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thanks 