# How to set an exact path inside findViewById()

Tags: android

If I use `findViewById` like this(first code) then I can't use same `id`(`usernameid`) in different layout:

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameid);
```

Is there any way to use like this (second code)? :

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.layout.activity-signup.id.usernameid);
```

Comment: As a matter of fact you can use same ID in different layouts .. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333624/can-i-use-the-same-id-in-different-layout-in-android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the same id in different layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333624/can-i-use-the-same-id-in-different-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

In Android you cant assign an View to layout with defined ID liked this

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.layout.activity-signup.id.usernameid);
```

the only way is passing EditText to EditText Id.

Answer (score 0):

In java file layout id of layout is already added in java file.